# Roles using Express 'No authorization token was found'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, auth0

Sup guys! I'm trying to implement Auth0 roles on my SPA, The login/log out functionality works fine.But doesn't know how to add roles permissions. The App its running at Heroku.

Here's my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const routes = require('./routes/index.js');
const cors = require('cors');
const { auth, requiresAuth} = require('express-openid-connect');
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const jwksRsa = require('jwks-rsa');
const jwtAuthz = require('express-jwt-authz');

require('./db.js');

const server = express();

server.name = 'API';

const config = {
  authRequired: false,
  auth0Logout: true,
  baseURL:"https://villatranquila.herokuapp.com/" ,
  clientID: "X0L9KdnZ9YanIX48y.......",
  issuerBaseURL:"https://dev-2py8q024.us.auth0.com/" ,
  secret:"5a64dw6f5h4f64u6ft565eqa6wq65w4x.........."
};

// auth router attaches /login, /logout, and /callback routes to the baseURL
server.use(auth(config));

const checkJwt = jwt({
  // Dynamically provide a signing key
  // based on the kid in the header and 
  // the signing keys provided by the JWKS endpoint.
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: `https://dev-2py8q024.us.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json`
  }),

  // Validate the audience and the issuer.
  audience: 'https://villatranquila.herokuapp.com/',
  issuer: `https://dev-2py8q024.us.auth0.com/`,
  algorithms: ['RS256']
});

// req.isAuthenticated is provided from the auth router
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.oidc.isAuthenticated() ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged out')
});

server.get('/profile', requiresAuth(),  (req, res) => {
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.oidc.user));
});

server.get('/api/private', checkJwt, function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    message: 'Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this.'
  });
});

const checkScopes = jwtAuthz([ 'admin:read' ]);

server.get('/api/private-scoped', checkJwt, checkScopes, function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    message: 'Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated and have a scope of read:messages to see this.'
  });
});

server.use(checkJwt);

server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
server.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
server.use(cookieParser());
server.use(cors());
server.use(morgan('dev'));
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  next();
});

server.use('/', routes);

// Error catching endware.
server.use((err, req, res, next) => { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  const status = err.status || 500;
  const message = err.message || err;
  console.error(err);
  res.status(status).send(message);
});

module.exports = server;
```

And here is the Heroku Application Logs ( App starts, I can get to non controlled routes, but when I try to reach controlled ones (/api/private or /api/private-scope) I get "No authorization token was found:"

```
2021-09-30T19:51:58.170228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api" host=villatranquila.herokuapp.com request_id=70de01d2-4b18-4ede-94c0-f375b1f7d81e fwd="186.39.49.142" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=401 bytes=2159 protocol=https
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169181+00:00 app[web.1]: UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169192+00:00 app[web.1]:     at middleware (/app/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:79:21)
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169193+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169193+00:00 app[web.1]:     at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169193+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169194+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169194+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express-openid-connect/middleware/auth.js:38:5
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169196+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'credentials_required',
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169197+00:00 app[web.1]:   status: 401,
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169197+00:00 app[web.1]:   inner: { message: 'No authorization token was found' }
2021-09-30T19:51:58.169197+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Can any one give me a hand here?